# Excel VBA TimeStamp

Tags: excel, vba, timestamp

I have a form set up to kick out entered information to the next available line. I need to time stamp each line of data that gets added. I am putting this in column A. I currently set up a formula using the Today() Function however every time i add a new line of data the previous dates get updated too (Say the data I entered on Friday now shows Tuesday). I could copy and paste special values each row but is there a better way to create a time stamp each time a user clicks a command button to add that data?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Cells(currentLine, 1).value = Date
```